# Search.php results from links

Tags: php, mysql

How do I display results from my Search.php page using a link on Index.php?

```
<a href="search.php?country_select=spain">Spain</a>
```

The above doesn't work and all countries are displayed in Search.php. Sorry i'm new to PHP and MySQL.

My link is on index.php and is to search and display on search.php. I have the following code on search.php:

```
<?php $appmt = $bsiCore->ClearInput(base64_decode($_REQUEST['appmt_id']));
$apartDetails = $bsiCore->getApartmentdetails($rowappt['appmt_id']);
$featuresarr = $bsiCore->getApmtFeatures($rowappt['appmt_id']);
?>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 single listing">


    <div class="offer offer-wrap">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo ($rowappt['default_img']=="")? "http://www.placehold.it/800x450/ddd/bbb&amp;text=Image":"gallery/ApartImage/".$rowappt['default_img']; ?>" alt="">
    <span class="label label-info">
    <?php echo $rowappt['country']; ?>
    </span>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="<?php echo str_replace(" ","-",strtolower(trim($rowappt['appmt_name'])))."-".$rowappt['appmt_id'].".html"; ?>"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button">Details</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button"><em class="icon-info-sign"></em></button></a>
      </div>
    <div class="padding img1">
    <h2 class="text-center text-info"><?php echo $rowappt['city']; ?></h2>
      <h4 class="text-center"><?php echo $rowappt['bedroom']; ?> bedroom, <?php echo $rowappt['bathroom']; ?> bathroom</h4>

      <span class="label2 label-info">
    <?php echo $bsiCore->config['conf_currency_symbol'].$rowappt['price']; ?><span>p/w*
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The form is as follows:

```
<form action="search.php" class="form-inline reservation-horizontal clearfix" role="form" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" style="padding-bottom:0px">  

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="min-height: 60px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);  border-radius: 5px;">

                    <div class="pad1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <select name="country_select"  id="drop_1">

  <option value="" selected="selected">All Countries</option>
</select> 
 </div>              

            <div>

            <div class="pad1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <select name="country_select">

  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Any City / Town</option>

</select> </div></div>

                <div class="pad1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <select id="appartment_type" name="appartment_type">
              <?php echo $bsiCore->getApmtTypeCombobox();?>
            </select>
            </div>



            <div class="pad1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <select name="bathroom" id="bathroom" >
                <option value="">Sleeps</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="See Description">16+</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="pad1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <button value="Search" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%;">Search</button>
           </div>  

           </div> 

            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: You'll need to add the code for search.php -- without knowing what it does, no one can answer your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I began writing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to answer your question, but I realized that I simply do not have enough information and still do not quite understand what you are asking.

Do you have an HTML form on `index.php` with an action that causes it to be submitted to `search.php`? Or do you have a link or set of links which the user can click, and the link that is selected controls what the user sees when sent to `search.php`?

Assuming you have a set of links on `index.php` that sends a `GET` request to your `search.php` page (as shown in your initial line of code `?country_select=spain`), are you then using this specific request to query a database? Or are you working from a set of data that is stored in a variable/array on the `search.php` page?

If you are submitting a form, it should look something like:

`index.php`

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
  <label>Select Country:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="country"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

`search.php`

```
<?php 
$country=$_POST['country'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `country_table` WHERE `country_name`= '".$country."'";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>
```

If you are using the option of multiple links, it may look something like this:

`index.php`

```
<p>Please select a country</p><br>
<a href="search.php?country_select=spain">Spain</a><br>
<a href="search.php?country_select=united+states">United States</a><br>
<a href="search.php?country_select=italy">Italy</a><br>
```

`search.php`

```
<?php
$country=$_GET['country_select'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `country_table` WHERE `country_name`= '".$country."'";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
```

Again, I do not know how your data is stored/formatted, I do not know how exactly you wish to present the search to the user, and I do not know what you wish to do with the result. For a more accurate response, please give a more detailed description of the issue and desired results.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the result data. The form is on both index.php and search.php.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that "country_select" is in your PHP receiving code as "$_REQUEST['country_select'];". Otherwise, it may be an issue with the parsing side of your search.php file. It could also be an issue whilst handling MySQL queries.